# Error when using getdataset() with join query

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have a below code which is giving error when I changed the sSQL parameter to join query. Earlier select command on  v_d_investigation view was there. I changed the query to join v_d_investigation on v_d_memo views. Error i am getting "One or more error occurred during processing of command. From keyword not found where expected". Please suggest on this...

```
        sSQL += "order by opened_dt Desc "

        fDataSet = gConn.getDataSet(sSQL, "v_d_investigation")
        'fDataSet = gConn.getDataSet(sSQL)
        totalRecords = Me.lvList.AddItems(fDataSet, "v_d_investigation")
```

Comment: The query syntax is incorrect - that's why this error is returned.  Please provide the full query, not just the `order by` concatenation.

Comment: Need a space? `sSQL += " order by opened_dt Desc "`